# Add metadata from database to Solr Index created by Nutch

Tags: solr, nutch, solr4

I have a bespoke CMS that needs to be searchable in Solr. Currently, I am using Nutch to crawl the pages based on a seed list generated from the CMS itself.

I need to be able to add metadata stored in the CMS database to the document indexed in Solr. So, the thought here is that the page text (html generated by the CMS) is crawled via Nutch and the metadata is added to the Solr document where the unique ID (in this instance, the URL) is the same.

As such, the metadata from the DB can be used for facets / filtering etc while full-text search and ranking is handled via the document added by Nutch.

Is this pattern possible? Is there any way to update the fields expected from the CMS DB after  Nutch has added it to Solr?

Answer (score 0):

Solr has the ability to partially update a document, provided that all your document fields are stored. See [this](http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/). This way, you can define several fields for your document, that are not originally filled by nutch, but after the document is added to solr by nutch, you can update those fields with your database values.

In spite of this, I think there is one major problem to be solved. Whenever nutch recrawls a page, it updates the entire document in solr, so your updated fields are missed. Even in the first time, you must be sure that nutch first added the document, and then the fields are updated. To solve this, I think you need to write a plugin for nutch or a special request handler for solr to know when updates are happening.

Comment: So the pattern would be:  
  
1 - Nutch crawls page  
2 - Nutch submits page to Solr  
3 - Execute update command against solr to retrieve extra fields from DB as per schema.xml and data-config.xml. Use url as id document to make sure same doc is updated  
4 - Document fields are updated and in sync (pages from Nutch, meta-data from DB)  
  
I think this should suffice as we don't require a continuous crawl of the source URLs, simply a periodic import of the crawled pages + meta-data from the DB.

I will try to build something thats workable and post it back here.